# Issue with list in Python

Tags: python

I'm a noob in Python. I saw this code and I don't quite understand it.

```
list_1 = ['History', 'Math', 'Physics', 'CompSci']
list_2 = list_1

print(list_1)
print(list_2)

list_1[0] = 'Art'

print(list_1)
print(list_2)
```

After the program is executed, I know the `list_1` is `['Art', 'Math', 'Physics', 'CompSci']` eventually, but why is the `list_2` also ['Art', 'Math', 'Physics', 'CompSci']. I mean, there's no `list_2 = list_1` after the second `print(list_1)`. Could someone help me out? Thanks!

## Update

I tried some new code.

```
a = 40
b = a
print(a)
print(b)

a = 50
print(a)
print(b)
```

And the result is

```
40
40
50
40
```

So this means, that problem I mentioned before is only for list, right? If I just have a normal variable like `a` and `b`, when I change the value of `a`, the value of `b` won't be affected.

Comment: You have one list with two names.

Comment: `list_2` is a reference to `list_1`. The keyword here is **reference**. All changes in `list_1` are reflected in `list_2`.

Comment: But, if you delete `list_1`, you'll still have `list_2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list_2 = list_1` makes `list_2` a *reference* to the exact same list that `list_1` references. Throughout this program there's only one list in memory.

This can be verified when printing the memory address:

```
list_1 = ['History', 'Math', 'Physics', 'CompSci']
list_2 = list_1

print(id(list_1))
# 5430888
print(id(list_2))
# 5430888
```

You should definitely read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 3):

After writing `list_2 = list_1`, the adress held by the `list_1` variable will be the same as the one held by `list_2`.

As a consequence, every change on `list_1` will be seen on `list_2` as well, since both variables will represent the same object.

You can check this by comparing the two variables' ids:

```
>>> id(list_1)
1518664319304
>>> id(list_2)
1518664319304
```

Or even better:

```
>>> list_1 is list_2
True
```

Comment: So if list_1 and list_2 are variables, then the changes of list_1 won't affect the value of list_2, right?

Comment: @S.Li You need to clearly understand what a variable is. It's like a box, with a number inside. If the variable is an int, a string, a float..., ie a "value type", then the content of the box is this value itself. If the variable is a list, a dictionary... ie a "reference type" or "compound type", then the content of the box is an **adress** to what the variables describes. When one writes `a = b`, the content of `b` is duplicated and goes into `a`. If it's a value, then taking the content of `a` and modifying it will not affest `b`.

Comment: @S.Li On the other hand, if the content of `a` is an address, it cannot be modified as is. Instead, the interpreter will look at this address, and change what's there. But the content of `a` is still the same as `b`'s: that one address. That's why changing what is at the address contained in `a` will be seen from `b` as well: they both refer to the same content.

Comment: I think I finally got it. Thanks for the explanation. That helps a lot!

Comment: @S.Li You're welcome :) Don't forget this. When strange things happen, especially when things change although they shouldn't, odds are great the same thing as here is happening.